# Unable to connect Lambda Layer in Keras directly to Flatten Layer without an exception. Why?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

System:

- Keras 1.0.1
- Theano 0.8.2

I've a very simple function:

```
from keras import backend as kback

def ave_embed(xval):
    return kback.mean(xval, axis=1)
```

I'm using this in a Keras `Lambda` Layer followed by a `Flatten` Layer:

```
model.add(Lambda(ave_embed, output_shape=(d, 1)))
model.add(Flatten())
```

However, when I compile the model, I get the following error:

```
Exception: Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten_1: expected ndim >= 3, found ndim=2
```

I fix it by doing the following:

```
model.add(Lambda(ave_embed, output_shape=(d, 1)))
model.add(Reshape(d,1))
model.add(Flatten())
```

Can anyone explain the cause for the exception?  It looks like I'm applying reshape on an output that should already be that shape.

Answer (score 0):

> It looks like I'm applying reshape on an output that should already be that shape.

You are right!

If you have a 3d input and take the mean accross the second dimension (`kback.mean(xval, axis=1)`) your `Lambda` layer will output you a 2d tensor.

For your combination of `Lambda` layer and `Flatten` layer to work, you should have at least a 4D input.

You just have to remove your `Flatten` layer to make it work.
Adding a `Reshape` layer and a dimension makes your input tensor of your `Flatten` layer 3d but with an unnecessary dimension that you flatten right after.